# This ODE $(\dot x,\dot y)=(f(x),g(x)y)$ has only one solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this question:

> Let $f,g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be continuous and Lipschitz. Prove
>   the initial value problem:
>
> $(\dot x,\dot y)=(f(x),g(x)y)$, $x(t_0)=x_0$, $y(t_0)=y_0$ has only
>   one solution in every interval.

I've tried to use the Picard theorem without success. I think maybe I have to adapt this theorem for this case.

I really need help.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the equation for $x$ does not involve $y$, you can solve it first as a single ODE:
$$\dot x = f(x), \quad x(t_0)=x_0\tag1$$
Since $f$ is globally Lipschitz, the Picard theorem implies that the solution of (1) exists for all times, and is unique. 
Now that $x$ is a known function, the equation for $y$ turns into a linear ODE 
$$\dot y = g(x)y, \quad y(t_0)=y_0\tag2$$
Here $g(x)$ is a continuous function of $t$, being the composition of two continuous functions. It follows that the solution of (2) exists for all times, and is unique.

---

Remark #1: "continuous and Lipschitz" is redundant. A Lipschitz function is automatically continuous.

---

Remark #2, concerning your [meta question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9111/bad-badge-tumbleweed). The Tumbleweed badge is not completely useless. It serves as a [catalog of overlooked questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/badges/40), and thus draws some (small) amount of attention toward them -- which is better than nothing.