# g(x)y is a Lipschitz function.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

In order to solve this question: [This ODE $(\dot x,\dot y)=(f(x),g(x)y)$ has only one solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353972/this-ode-dot-x-dot-y-fx-gxy-has-only-one-solution).

I'm trying to prove that $g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, $g(x)y$ is a Lipschitz function, I don't know why, but I found this a little bit strange to prove.

I need help

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As was pointed out in the other solution, a Lipschitz condition applies to $f$ and so a unique solution exists for the ODE $\dot{x} = f(x)$. Let $x(t)$ be this solution.  Then you need to show that for each $t$, the function $\gamma(y,t) = g(x(t)) y$ is locally Lipschitz in $y$.

You have $|\gamma(y,t)-\gamma(y',t)| = |g(x(t))| \|y - y' \|$. Since $x,g$ are continuous, $|g(x(t))|$ is bounded on bounded time intervals. Hence $y \mapsto \gamma(y,t)$ is locally Lipschitz in $y$.

Comment: In the context of Picard theorem, we don't have to prove that this funtion is Lipschitz in the second variable? Thanks a lot for your clarification!

Comment: Well, the usual version assumes continuity in $t$ and Lipschitz continuity in the state variable. The trick here is to solve the 'f' equation first to get $x$, then this turns $g(x)$ into a function of '$t$'.

Comment: I understood, thanks again